# Javafx drag and drop get source

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx

I have code implementing javafx drag and drop similar to http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/HelloDragAndDrop.java.html
I want to test if the user has droped the image in the correct area 
I don't know if there is a method to get the source and get the target so that I can check if the source match the correct target.
I am using the this visual interface:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6241504/3-2-2013%207-35-50%20PM.png
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7):

You can get the the gesture source and the target too, so you can easily check wether your source and target is equal or you can accept it or not. You need to cast to the specific type!

```
event.getGestureSource();
```

or

```
event.getGestureTarget();
```

Comment: thank you for your help.here is how I solved my problem :I added hidden Text("1") Text("2") ... to the nodes. and in the drop area I compare these Text values when it match the answer is correct.

Comment: i would not recommend the solution you described. Also consider picking this answer as the "right" one, as it clearly does what you asked for and is probably the nicest solution